# SQLite and Android Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing problem in android application i want to create database with following script.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
source_device_id INT,
timestamp INT NOT NULL,
processed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
event_type TINYINT NOT NULL,
payload BLOB);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS events_unprocessed ON events (processed, _id);
```

and my android code is

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  InputStream schemaStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.logdb_schema);
  Scanner schemaScanner = new Scanner(schemaStream, "UTF-8");
  schemaScanner.useDelimiter(";");

  Log.i(TAG, "Creating database");
  try {
    db.beginTransaction();
    while (schemaScanner.hasNext()) {
      String statement = schemaScanner.next();
      Log.d(TAG, "Creating database: " + statement);
      db.execSQL(statement);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
  }
  finally {
    db.endTransaction();
  }
}
```

Its not working its generating run-time exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error:

Comment: *What* run-time exception?  We need the details if you want help.

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error

Comment: If I use that with `sqlite3` command it works. That can't be the whole error, there must be more. Please check your [logcat output](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-log.html#startingLogcat) and post it here...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because of whitespace after the last semicolon in my schema. My java code was executing that whitespace as a separate query.

On Froyo it complains, on Ice Cream Sandwich it doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: I've seen the same problem of whitespace after the last semicolon on tablets: on Jelly Bean it throws android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error, on Honeycomb it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

My guess would that you are using a BOOLEAN & TINYINT type which are not supported.  You need to use INTEGER instead

Comment: I have check query in sqllite editor such SQLLITEpro 2009 its working fine there in my android application its not working

Comment: It clearly says (section 2.2), that those are supported by the parser.  They just map to NUMERIC and INTEGER respectively.

Comment: Has anyone actually tried it because I know boolean does not work from experience

Comment: @Joe, yes it does.  `CREATE TABLE t (b BOOLEAN NOT NULL);` works fine; as I said it maps to NUMERIC.  Download the command-line version and try for yourself.